# Missing data from collection when looping

Tags: loops, collections, missing-data, rpa, blueprism

I am facing an issue of missing data when looping the data in collection. Let me explain in detail,

Process :
1.Firstly a data report from sap has to be downloaded .
2.using get collection action taking all the data into collection(named as : data collection).
3.After getting in to collection for checking the data we are looping and checking if the data in collection is matching to reference data or not if matched we are adding the values to another new collection(named as : filtered collection).

Problem: The data collection has 4700 rows , when this data collection is looped over and adding matching values from reference to filtered collection some values are missing in filtered collection. And when this process is run multiple times most of the time the missing data in filtered collection has once 4400 rows another time 4663 rows etc.

The data is also correct when this missing data is lopped again the data is getting added to filtered collection.

If anyone face the same issue or anyone can let me know what is the problem and help me in resolving the issue.